# Linear independence of a Matrix and its Transpose

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

I have a quick question.

I got an $m\times n$ matrix $M$ of which I know that the columns are linearly independent.

$M^T$  (its transpose) is then an $n\times m$ matrix with linearly independent rows.

If I multiply $M^T$ with $M$ I get an $n\times n$ matrix. Does this new matrix then also have linearly independent columns?

Comment: Dear @uniquesolution, I find it both funny and sad that you edit a post to correct its spelling, and turn "its transpose" into "it's transpose". Man, this is a disease among English-speaking persons, already!

Comment: Sorry, Alex -- I was trying to correct a formatting issue - from $mxn$ to $m\times n$. However, the ingenious system only allows editing of minimum 6 characters. As I am pretty much annoyed by mathematical dis-formatting issues, I just had to do something about it. I apologize from the depths of my heart if I have offended you.

Answer (score 2):

Not necesarily. This is only true if $n\geq m$, because the rank of $A=MM^T$ is always $n$ if the rank of $M$ is $n$. Therefore, if $m>n$, $A$ would be a $m\times m$ matrix with rank $n$, therefore it would not have linearly independent columns.

For example, if $M=\begin{bmatrix}1 \\ -1\end{bmatrix}$ then $MM^T = \begin{bmatrix}1 & -1\\ -1 & 1\end{bmatrix}$ and the two columns are not linearly independent.

Comment: Hmm, I thought the OP meant $M^TM$ rather than $MM^T$, as seen from his description of the matrices' dimensions.

Comment: @user1551 Well then the answer just flips, so it is only true if $n\leq m$. The reasoning stays the same.